# Cannot install MySQL on fresh CentOS 7 server

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, centos7

I just installed MySQL on a fresh installation of Linux CentOS, but when mysql-server finished installing and I enter "systemctl start mysqld" it says:

"Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code."

[systemctl status mysqld.service -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLgL0.png)

[tail -f /var/log/mysqld.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTIuZ.png)

I have tried installing removing and installing mysql a few times, tried installing on another new VM but I get the same issues. Tried as both user with sudo and as root without success.

When entering "systemctl status mysqld" I get the information in the picture below. I find no information in there that helps me. Tried checking "journalctl -xe" and in the log (/var/log/mysqld.log) but nothing seems to lead me to a fix when googling what I find there.

In the log it says several ERRORS. Like "Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist" and "priviliege system failed to initialize correctly....upgrade MySQL to a new version..". Tried looking for threads with these same error-codes but with no luck.

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Installation of mysql on centos7 is pretty straight forward .

one way is to follow below steps:

wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql80-community-release-el7.rpm

sudo rpm -ivh mysql80-community-release-el7.rpm

sudo yum install mysql-server

sudo systemctl start mysqld

sudo systemctl status mysqld

sudo mysql_secure_installation

Comment: Tried exactly this 5-6 times with the same issue occurring. However, I tried installing another image of Centos 7 and also with an image of Centos 9 in virtualbox, and then installing mysql with the same procedure as you mention and then it worked without any issues. Seems like the version we had available perhaps had issues in it I guess?

Comment: it depends could be , because steps are common for centos distro. if all other conditions are kept constant then may be centos7 image that you have might have issue with mysql installation

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of searching for potential answers online without success, I instead tried installing a VM with another image of Centos 7 and also with an image of Centos 9 in virtualbox, and then installing mysql with the same procedure as you mention and then it worked without any issues.

The version that was used when the problems occurred was: 'CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-DVD.iso'

Using the latest Centos 7 and/or Centos 9 Stream iso from the official website seems to give better results with installing MySQL..